# How to authenticate with an external 3rd party API from a single page Nuxt application over oauth?

Tags: vue.js, authentication, oauth, nuxt.js, single-page-application

I have a Nuxt application that interacts with NationBuilder, a 3rd party application. In order for users on my site to interact with data from their NationBuilder account, my app must allow them to authenticate over OAuth with the NationBuilder API.

The first step of this OAuth process works fine; My client sends a request to the NationBuilder API's /oauth/authorize endpoint. The browser redirects the user to NationBuilder's website where the user can login to grant my application access to their NationBuilder data. Then, NationBuilder redirects the user back to a second page on my site with query parameter in the URL containing what is called the "code". This second page on my site hits our internal API with this code, which in turn hits the Nationbuilder API's /oauth/token endpoint with the code to receive the access_token. Now we can use this access_token in any call to the Nationbuilder API.

The issue I'm running into is that when Nationbuilder first redirects the user to that second page in our Nuxt app, the reloading of my site takes a while and seems to be skipping some initialization configuration steps. I think this is the case because some of the functions that normally work when I boot up my site are not found.

I am in the process of developing the application, so I am running my site on localhost and using ngrok to create an https tunnel to satisfy the NationBuilder API. Maybe this issue is related to the tunneling?

I have a hunch I should be doing this all differently. If there is a conventional way of authenticating a Nuxt application with a 3rd party application over OAuth, please point me to an example/docs.

Cheers.

Comment: It sounds like you're on the right path, but you may have some routing issues to sort out. I would start by grabbing the redirect URL that NationBuilder is redirecting your page to after /authorize, and try to load it directly in a separate tab. If that works, turn on Chrome inspector's network tab with "Preserve log", try the flow from the start, and see if you can catch where the problem happens.

Comment: Did you have a look to using a third-party service to handle the authentication? I'm a contributor to [Pizzly](https://github.com/bearer/pizzly), an open-source project that has been developed exactly for a use case like yours. Here's a tutorial on [how to use Pizzly in a Vue.js app](https://dev.to/bearer/how-to-use-an-oauth-based-api-in-vue-js-1elo).